Schrödinger equation quadratic potential
I am interested in the equation $y''(x) = (2a + x^{2}) y(x)$:

In particular, I am interested in which values the parameter $a$ yield solutions which are bounded at infinity.
I am aware that it is a well-known result that the only values of $a$ which give bounded solutions of this equation are $a = -n - 1/2$ where $n$ is a non-negative integer.
I am also aware that the change of variables
$y(x) = \exp(-x^{2}/2)f(x)$ transforms our equation into
the Hermite differential equation and that this leads to bounded solutions of the form $\exp(-x^{2}/2)H_{n}(x)$ where $H_{n}(x)$ is the $n$th Hermite polynomial.
I am aware that that standard proof is often written in books uses the a series solution to the Hermite differential equation Using these formulas we can determine a differential equation for $f(x)$ namely
\begin{align}
    f''(x) - 2x f'(x) + 2\nu f(x) = 0 
\end{align}
Suppose that we seek solution of this equation in the form of a power series
\begin{align*}
    f(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_{k}x^{k}.
\end{align*}
Differentiating term by term gives us
$$
    f_{1}'(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} k a_{k} x^{k-1}\\
    f_{1}''(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} k(k-1) a_{k} x^{k-2}.
$$
Substituting into the Hermite differential equation and setting all of the coefficients equal to zero gives the equations
$$
    a_{k+2} = 2\left(k - \nu\right)a_{k} / \left(\left(k+1\right)\left(k+2\right)\right).
$$

This means that we can express a general solution $f(x)$ in terms of the two solutions $ f_{1}\left(x\right) = 1 - \nu x^{2} - \nu \left(2 - \nu\right) x^{4}/6 + \cdots$ and $ f_{2}\left(x\right) = x + \left(1 - \nu\right) x^{3}/3 + \left(3-\nu\right)\left(1-\nu\right)x^{5}/30 + \cdots.$ If $\nu$ is an integer than one these two series will terminate otherwise both the series for $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ will have infinitely many terms.

In most proofs is it taken as obvious that these solutions have exponential behavior as $x \to \infty$ when $\nu$ is not an integer however, I don't feel I understand why exactly these series behave exponentially.
What I'm looking for is either a proof that these are the only solutions which are bounded at $\infty$ that is fully rigorous or a reference which can be cited as proof of this fact.
I have been looking online and in books about special functions for a long time and any help with this would be very much appreciated.


The proof that these are the only bounded solutions comes from solving for the functions $f$. The technique is to use the Frobenius method, and during the solution process one finds that solutions are similar to that of an exponential function unless we truncate the series as a polynomial. Consider finding resources for how to solve the Hermite differential equation to see.

Hi Josh. I knew that the Hermite differential equation can be solved using a series solution. I've edited my question to reflect this and hopefully better explain my difficulties.

Bender and Orszag contains has a wonderful chapter on Parabolic Cylinder functions. In particular on page 133 example 9 they give the eigenvalues of the Parabolic Cylinder equation and provide a clear explantion of why these are the only eigenvalues. Hopefully this is helpful to someone in the feature.

The general solutions of the oscillator Hamiltonian are parabolic cylinder functions $D_k(\sqrt 2 x), D_k(i \sqrt 2 x)$ which are not in $\mathit L_2(\mathbb R,dx)$ except for  the cases, when they reduce  to Hermite polynomials times the  Gaussian ground state measure.
Both linearly independent solutions for non.1/2-integer indices are growing  exponentially at one of the infinties.
  DSolve[1/2 (-y''[x] + x^2 y[x]) == (n + 1/2) y[x], y[x], x]

   ParabolicCylinderD[n, Sqrt[2] x]

For integer indiex n we have e.g.
    ParabolicCylinderD[7, Sqrt[2] x]/(E^(-(x^2/2)) HermiteH[7, x]) //   
     FunctionExpand

$$\frac{1}{8\sqrt 2 }$$
but
$$\underset{x\to \infty }{\text{lim}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}} D_{0.5}\left(\sqrt{2} x\right)=0$$
$$\underset{x\to -\infty }{\text{lim}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}} D_{0.5}\left(\sqrt{2} x\right)=-\infty$$
This is the standard case of the eigenvalue problem for a linear ODE of second with rational coefficients: they have an essential singularity at complex infinity. For the eigenvalue the algebraic eigenfunction degenerates to a square integrable function on the real line.
The complex Gaussian ground state $e^{-z^2}$ is characteristical, it takes any complex value in the vincinity of $z=\infty$. All other eigenstates are derivatives with polynomial coefficients.
The parabolic cylinder functions have to be used on a finite real interval of the oscillator eigenvalue problem.
This happens for the electron states in a 2d-strip in a magnetic field, that reduces to the 1-d oscillator in an intervall and yields the normal Hall effect for strip width small compared to the width of the Gaussian ground state.
The quantum Hall effect occurs for the width of the strip being large compared to the extension of the oscillator states, both in case of a constant current along the strip.
